# Can a URL query string contain a period?

Tags: php, http, url

I have URLs like this:

```
process_request.php?fileName=newpage.html
```

I attempt to retrieve the `fileName` parameter with:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) { ... }
```

It's not working and I'm wondering if the period in the file name could be the problem. I can't seem to find a definitive answer. PHP's URL encoding functions don't appear to do anything to periods.

Comment: The PHP URL encode function doesn't touch them so I think it should be there. How are you trying to read it? Per PHP `Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs` http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php Maybe you have rewriting in place and aren't passing over the original value?

Comment: The result is empty

Comment: I don't know what "having rewriting in place" means

Comment: You probably don't have it in that case. Output your request and see what it is.

Comment: See `access.log`, `var_dump($_SERVER);` and browser inspection for debugging. The mixed case parameter hints foremost at usage errors. And `isset`  notice supression should **not** be used until code works as expected. VTC because of the omitted sample code `{ ... }`.

Answer (score 2):

## Fullstops (periods `.`) *are* valid query string values.

why? Because:

```
print urlencode("This is a ... query string! hazzah");
```

outputs:

> This+is+a+...+query+string%21+hazzah

Therefore this is not the cause of your apparent issue.

## How to find your *actual* issue:

- Re-run your code with the `fileName` param not containing a `.` and seeing if the code runs as expected:

  > process_request.php?fileName=newpage.html

  ```
  if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) { print "it worked!"; die; }
  ```
- `var_dump()` the `$_REQUEST['fileName']` value to check it is what you expect (for instance `$_REQUEST` variables may be turned off in PHP.ini).

  > process_request.php?fileName=newpage.html

  ```
   var_dump($_REQUEST);
   if (isset($_REQUEST['fileName'])) { print "it worked!"; die; }
  ```
- Check your `.htaccess` (or similar) is not rewriting your actioning URL
- Check that the `if(...)` statement ***IS*** running and just not giving you the expected result due to another issue, error or failure.

## And last but not least....

- [READ YOUR PHP ERROR LOG!!!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)